# cannot create a bot in xcode 14?

Tags: xcode, bots, product, xcode14

There r no details. I wanted to create a bot for my research project, but I needed it to operate on macOS and iOS devices, I already had Xcode 14 installed and had a little mess on it before so I found it easier to continue this way.

I was searching and noticed that under the "product" there should be a "create bot" which I lack, can anyone help, please? should I instal an extension or such first?

just a newbie asking a newbier question.

this is my first time here I don't know what to do!

Comment: What are "OS devices"? Do you mean macOS? iOS? Something else? Why Xcode 14? Xcode 15 is the current version of Xcode.

Comment: yup exactly, I want it to operate on both macOS and iOS devices (I know it's not as simple), and Idk, this was just what I had, do you suggest I get Xcode 15?
also I'm on macOS Monterey.